# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'school.message_test'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redis, asgi

I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a module in my Django project. Here's the code snippet:

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from school.message_test.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'school.settings')
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

specifically on this line:

```
from school.message_test.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
```

I've double-checked that all the paths are correct, and the file is in the right directory. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
to run the project I used this command:

```
daphne -p 8000 school.asgi:application
```

I'll try to use a relative path which naturally won't work. I also tried using it for the top level, that is

```
from ..message_test.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
```

but it doesn't work because asgi doesn't allow it the path is absolutely correct, what can you tell me?
[photo of the full project path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AsBK.png)
also the code from message_test/routing.py

```
# routing.py

from django.urls import re_path
from school.message_test.consumers.chat_consumer import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

also the code from the root of the routing project

```
# school/routing.py

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import school.message_test.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),

    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            school.message_test.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: Hello @Diyar, Can you please remove the school and import like this: from message_test.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
if it is not working then try this path:
from school.school.message_test.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
I think this may resolve the issue. Happy Coding...!! :)